# If you're already using a framework, should you never write "plain vanilla" js?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, javascript-framework

This is more of a question of style and preference than anything, though it's possible that there might be performance considerations as well.

If you're using a framework (say jQuery for the sake of argument, though it could be any framework) and you need to write a new function. It's a simple function, and you could easily accomplish it without using the framework.

Is there an advantage to using the framework anyway, because it's already loaded in the browser's memory, has a readily-accessible map of the DOM, etc.? Or will plain-vanilla js always parse faster because it's "raw" and doesn't depend on the framework?

Or is it simply a matter of taste?

Answer (score 7):

The answer is going to depend greatly on what you're working to accomplish.  In general, you're guaranteed at least a minor performance penalty for function overhead if you use a framework to achieve something that can be accomplished using "vanilla" JavaScript.  This performance penalty is typically nominal and can be disregarded when taking other advantages of your framework into mind (speed of development, cleaner code, ease of maintenance, reusable code, etc).

If you absolutely have to have the most efficient code possible then you should try to write pure JavaScript that's highly optimized.  If, like in most real world scenarios, you're not concerned about a handful of milliseconds in performance difference, stick with your Framework to maintain consistency.

Comment: True. Most of the heavier stuff with javascript involves messing with the DOM. I've been benchmarking jQuery selectors the last few days and even the complicated selectors take microseconds. It is MUCH more important to optimise your code in standard ways, e.g. reusing variables, not putting selectors inside of loops etc, as you would with vanilla JS. The actual performance hit of the framework is negligable.

Answer (score 3):

There's always something to learn when you're solving problems with pure JS as opposed to having external code do it for you. In the long run, it's more maintainable because it's *your* code. It's not going to change. You know what it does. That's where the value of solving your own problems really comes into play. If you do your research on [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533050%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), and the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf), cross-browser scripting becomes a lot easier to process. Sure, Microsoft has their own ideas and their own DOM, but that's where the fun (read: challenge) is.

Cross-browser scripting in pure JS really heightens your problem-solving ability along with your understanding of the language. If there still are things that confound you, then jQuery can come into the mix and bridge the mental gap, so to speak. It's great to drive around in a luxury vehicle, but what use is it if you don't know how to change a tire when it goes flat? The best jQuery devs are the ones that know JavaScript well and know when to use jQuery, and when to use plain JS.

Sometimes, you just have to roll up your sleeves and do some hard work. There isn't a jQuery plugin for *everything*, and jQuery can't hide you from all the quirks that various browsers have to offer. Getting the job done with your own code is very rewarding, even if you had to sweat it out to make it work.

It's perfectly acceptable to use many different tools to complete a singular task. You just need to know when and where to use them.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of jQuery it doesn't actually maintain a map of the dom in Memory and just has cross browser methods for walking the dom. Somethings will natually be faster in some browsers over others (such as a class based selector in Firefox will be faster than in IE because IE doesn't have a built in function for getElementsByClassName and Firefox does). If you don't need the frameworks methods for doing things I would say go ahead and use the native JS as that is generally what you chosen framework will use.

Answer (score 1):

I would say do it with the framework, just because it will bring consistency inside the project. If you are using the framework everywhere even in small function, it will be easier to maintain.

As for the other factor it really depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a javascript-heavy project. I've found that almost every time I had a cross-browser bug in my code, it was in a place where I had code like this:

```
var element = $(selector);
// lots of code ...
element[0].someVanillaOperation();
```

and that vanilla wasn't exactly the same across all browsers. What I love about jQuery is that (most of the time) it hides the browser differences and its functions work the same across them all.

Comment: Note that I'm only referring to pure JavaScript bugs here; HTML/CSS rendering issues are not in scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you're selecting elements by ID then plain Javascript is faster.  It doesn't, however, provide any of the selection niceties that you get with jQuery - selecting multiple elements by class in a single call, for example.

Take a look at this link: http://www.webkit.org/perf/slickspeed/ which runs a speed test.  It's an older version of jQuery, but the results in terms of raw speed speak for themselves.

Personally, I tend to use jQuery for everything - it keeps the code cleaner and the fact it pretty much dispenses with cross-browser JS support issues is worth any performance overhead in my book.

Comment: Ironically, the tests on that link fail with a javascript error when I tried it (Chrome).

Comment: @jamietre: lol! Really? I'm on build 10.0.648.204 and they're fine for me.  They're basically saying that all those tests perform faster natively.

Comment: Worked in firefox. Some sort of frame issue.  `frameworks[iframe.name] = { 'test': window.frames[iframe.name].test,...` .. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined". Obviously, they shouldn't have used native JS to set up the tests. :)

Comment: Anyway... I've yet to develop something with jQuery that was a problem (performancewise) even in IE6. Though I do tend to use native for some really basic things like `id`.

Comment: ...and therein lies the lesson... :)

Comment: @jamietre: I completely agree - it offers too many advantages to *not* use it as far as I'm concerned.